# Sum using loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and specifically need to find the min, max, and average of the age column using loops. However, try as I   might. It just did not work. I hope somebody could help me see where the problem is. Thank you.

Here is my code

```
total_age = 0
i=0
max_amount = adult_data["age"][i]
min_amount = adult_data["age"][i]
for i in range(len(adult_data["age"])):
    total_age = adult_data["age"][i] + total_age,
    i = i + 1,
    if adult_data["age"][i] > max_amount:
        max_amount = adult_data["age"][i],
    if adult_data["age"][i] < min_amount:
        min_amount = adult_data["age"][i],
print(total_age)
```

The error I am currently getting is
`ValueError: key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex`

Comment: Lookup .iloc I think that should help you with your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas at the end of statements indicate *tuples*. For example, `i = i + 1,`is the same as `i = (i + 1,)`, where `(i + 1,)` is a tuple with one element.

So, your code is essentially the same as:

```
for i in range(len(adult_data["age"])):
    total_age = (adult_data["age"][i] + total_age,)
    i = (i + 1,)
    if adult_data["age"][i] > max_amount:
        max_amount = (adult_data["age"][i],)
    if adult_data["age"][i] < min_amount:
        min_amount = (adult_data["age"][i],)
```

That's a lot of tuples!

In other words, you don't need the commas. You also don't need `i = i + 1` because the `range` automatically increments `i`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I was devastated not knowing what went wrong. Sometimes I just feel so down learning programming language since something seems  as commas can change the whole outcome and I just couldn't figure the problem out on my own. Sorry for the rant but I really do appreciate your help in making my learning journey a little bit less stressful.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
adult_data["age"].agg(['min','max','mean'])
```

Comment: Thank you. I have finally solved the problem (deleting the commas at the end of a few lines). My instructor however specifically said to use loop to solve this problem without using built-in function. It is nice to know another way to tackle this problem though.